# iOS different bundle ids map to the same app

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook-login, deep-linking, xcode-scheme

I'm trying to follow the convention described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796159/manage-ios-enterprise-developer-program) to manage both an app store and enterprise version of the same app but am seeing some really interesting behavior.

As described in the linked answer I've created a new scheme, defined a new 'Enterprise' build configuration and set up the enterprise scheme to use a separate and new bundle id. Both schemes point to the same target which relies on the new build config to toggle behavior. I am successfully able to generate an enterprise build and distribute it over-the-air, however, when I install both versions of the same app on the same simulator or phone **the enterprise version actually runs the app store version of the app.** Any changes that I make that are enterprise specific do not get reflected. Even when I close the app - the iOS7 animation back to the home screen animates back to the app store icon - not the enterprise one.

Obviously I want to be able to maintain these as separate versions that run independently. I feel like I must be fundamentally misunderstanding targets and schemes to get this kind of behavior. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty interesting bug.

What was happening was:

- We were using facebook login to authenticate with our own services on the enterprise version.
- The FB SDK would take over and kick out to a web/view or the fb app, depending on it's own logic. Critically - we were using the same facebook "app" configured on their developer site.
- When fb returned it would call the url scheme denoted by `fb{app_id}`
- iOS decided (consistently) to open the app that was first-installed that would respond to that URL scheme. In most cases this was the app-store version NOT the enterprise version.

The solution for this - maybe obviously at this point - is to use two different facebook apps so that iOS can route the returning OAuth response to the proper app. In keeping with the answer that I was originally working off this is best done by...

- Creating a new user defined build setting entitled `FACEBOOK_ID`
- Use your production app id for Debug and Release, while using the new id for Enterprise.
- In your info.plist, change the value of your `FacebookAppID` to be `${FACEBOOK_ID}`
- In your URL Types, change the facebook scheme to be `fb${FACEBOOK_ID}`
- This should successfully route your facebook login.

Keep in mind this is a general potential bug for ALL deep links - not just facebook login.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to use `URL Scheme Suffix` instead of separate Facebook apps. With URL Scheme Suffix you can add suffixes to the bundle id, for example: com.example.App.live and com.example.App.beta. That way the Facebook url scheme knows which app to open after authentication.

See the documentation on Facebook's developer site for more into: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/troubleshooting#sharedappid